# Imagick 3 writeImages() function not working

Tags: php, imagick

I can't find any bugs online but since switching to Imagick 3 from 2.1 I can't use the writeImages() function in the proper way.  An image is saved, but it's not animated any more.  I've set the frames up correctly because if I `echo $gif` I get the animation.

```
$gif = new Imagick();
$gif->setFormat("gif");

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $frame = new Imagick();
    $frame->readImage($file);
    $gif->addImage($frame);
    $gif->setImageDelay(1);
}

$path = "/any/path/will/do/animation.gif";
$gif->writeImages($path,true);
```

Comment: This is weird, I can't replicate this behavior. Have you tried something like `file_put_contents('animation.gif', $gif);`?

Comment: Hi Rob, I raised it as a bug, it's now fixed https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a bug in PHP
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61879